# Read Data into Google Colab Environment

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, pickle, load-data-infile

I am trying to run a sentiment analysis code in google colab to increase the processing speed compared to running the code on my device. But I am running into a strange error, which I am not able to solve.

I mounted the drive using the following code:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

Then I want to load a Pickle-File, which I have saved in MyDrive using the following code:

```
with open('/content/drive/MyDrive/data_colab_new.pkl', 'rb') as file:
    data = pickle.load(file)
```

But I get the following error message:

EOFError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
2 with open('/content/drive/MyDrive/data_colab_new.pkl', 'rb') as file:
3     # Load the pickle file
----> 4     data = pickle.load(file)

**EOFError: Ran out of input**

I already googled and the only explantion I found was that the Pickle-File is empty. But I checked multiple times now and I am sure that the file is not empty.

What could be another reason for that error and do you know any way to fix it? I`m not able to figure it out myself.

Answer (score 0):

use this in google colab to load the pickle file first.

```
from google.colab import files
files.upload()
```

then pickle load like this

```
f = open('model.pkl', 'rb')
model = pickle.load(f)
```